# What song are these lyrics from (translated into emojis)

Tags: knowledge, rebus, music, emoji

- Each emoji stands for 1 English word: there are no combo words.
- The candle ️ is a classical European art motif. When a candle is on, you are living! If the candle goes out, you're dead. If you watch Ridley Scott's movie on Moses, you'll see it in that context.
- The arrow ⬇️ is a direction.
- There is a comma, so before it, is a clause.
- The money : it clearly has to do something with money, and if you don't have money, you can't ... something.
- The couch ️ is figurative, it is not a couch, but it is a noun though: maybe something related to comfortable.
- The emojis have to be read first from left to right, line by line, from top to bottom, just like you would with normal English text.

️⬇️,   this  
a ️ ✊

➡️  2️⃣, ▶️
❓‍♂️ ✊ (I go) ⛔▶️✝️

- Responding to the comment that some of the emojis aren't visible, here is a screenshot of the same attached: [image]

Comment: Are the parentheses part of the lyrics/sentence, or are they just to show that the words "I" and "go" belong there?

Comment: @Stevish What I can tell you is that the parentheses are there for a reason, they are not accidental.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The song is

> **[Where Could I Go But to the Lord](https://www.lyrics.com/lyric-lf/362348/Elvis+Presley/Where+Could+I+Go+But+to+the+Lord)** by Elvis Presley

The part of the lyrics being described.

> ‘**Living below in this old sinful world hardly a comfort can afford.
>
>  Striving alone to face temptation so now won't you tell me. Where could I go but to the Lord**?’

Why?

> Living (️) below (⬇️) in () this old () sinful () world () hardly () a comfort (️) can (✊ ‘*power to do*’) afford ().

> Striving () alone (➡️*according to the OP because it is close to Along*) to (2️⃣) face ( *the hand is facing something*) temptation () so (▶️ *therefore*) Now won't you tell me ( *silent* *and ❓ question*) where (‍♂️) could (✊ again ‘*power to do*’) I go but to the Lord? ( *everywhere is blocked ⛔ except to ▶️ GOD ✝️*).

Comment: [ ] Each emoji stands for 1 English word

Comment: @sarsaparilla, yeah, I saw that too... looked like OP pulled a fast one on us with that part of the description.

Comment: @Sarsaparilla they do all stand for a word but they don’t all stand for a word IN THE LYRICS. In the second half the emojis are standing for words in statements which  are implied from the lyrics. So I don’t think the op is technically wrong but I agree it was certainly misleading.

Comment: If I were to make a puzzle like this I would certainly make all of them more clearly correspond to the words of the lyrics. Personally I felt some of the emojis were a stretch.

Comment: @PDT The intention of the emoji which you marked with (...?) was as follows: if you change the last letter of the word of the lyrics (e to g), then you find the meaning of the emoji.